# what is the best way to extract a part of a string from a given string?

Tags: java, android, string, wordpress

ok i have two strings and both has a string  (a name of a person) which i want. so i can process anyone of them to get that name from the string. the problem is which one would be more efficient to use and best way to use it. these are two strings :  String 1-

```
<p><a href=\"http://abinet.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/molestation1.jpg
 \" ><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-714\" src=\"http://abine
t.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/molestation1.jpg\" alt=\"molestation\" 
width=\"540\" height=\"393\" /></a></p>\n<p><strong>Krishna Pujari</str
ong></p>\n<p>A 25-year-old man was Sunday arrested in Kerala on charges
of raping his mother, media reports.</p>\n<p>“This was happening for s
ome time and there used to be ruckus in their home over this. The nei.....
```

String 2:

```
 <p>Krishna Pujari A 25-year-old man was Sunday arrested in Kerala on charges
 of raping his mother, media reports. “This was happening for some time and there 
 used to be ruckus in their home over this. The neighbours were unhappy over this 
 and filed a complaint and we arrested the man,” said a police official at …</p>\n
 ghbours were unhappy over this and filed a complaint and we arrested 
 the man,” said a police official at the Pala police station.</p>\n<p>
```

In both the string what i want is "Krishna Pujari". In first string it here in this line: between strong (means bold in wordpress).

```
<strong>Krishna Pujari</strong>
```

And in the second string it is the first word after:

```
<p>
```

This data comes from a website using json api. At times it is possible that the string will not have that name. So the first string will not have

```
<strong>Krishna Pujari</strong>
```

and the String 2 will have no name after:

```
<p>
```

it will diretly start from " A 25-year-old man was Sunday...". when this happens i do not want to extract any string at all. 
This is the code which i am using to extract that name is :

```
int startIndex = content.indexOf("<strong>")+8;
        String substring = content.substring(startIndex, startIndex+500);
        int subendIndex = substring.indexOf("</strong></p>");
        int endIndex = startIndex + subendIndex;
        String short_content = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

And this is working. However i feel this is not the correct way to do it as i cannot depend on this code. Because it will crash if it does not find /strong> (when the name is not there). Or when the name is not there and some other word in that string is bold (it will be in /strong> ) then it will give me that word which i don't want.

Please tell me the best way to extract that name. The only possibilities are that there are only a few names (4-5) which will be there or there wont be any name at all.

My question might take a little time to understand but might be easy to answer. I am just new to programming. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` to extract the name inside the tag of `strong`instead of calculating the `substring` which is not a good idea.

**sample:**

```
    try {
        String s = "<strong>Krishna Pujari</strong>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<strong>(.+?)</strong>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        m.find();
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // this wont close your app
    }
```

Comment: ok.. but what about when that line is not there (String s). Then it will have nothing to compile and it will crash.

Comment: @AbhinavRaja if it is not there?? then what would be the string look like and where is the name located?

Comment: that is the thing. then the string will be empty and the name shall not be displayed in the app. It is a news application which displays news. that name is the editor's name. In some news the editor name is not given. That time i will not be displaying any name at all.

Comment: @AbhinavRaja you can catch the error instead so your app wont close.

Comment: @AbhinavRaja you are welcome I change above code for finding string with sapce